# is there more elegant way to write this condition?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, if-statement, conditional-statements

I want a smaller way to write this condition I've tried to simplify it but it doesn't work with me

```
if(( data.includes(userId) || data.includes(userId.toString())  || data.includes(username) )) console.log(true)
```

this condition works very good but I want a simplified version of it

Comment: i guess you could probably get rid of the first `data.includes(userId)`

Comment: You could use `if(data.find(v => v == userId || v == username))` but I'm not sure this is simpler.

Comment: yes thats right and I want to use data once

Comment: @Titus yes that what I want

Comment: `let bool = (data.includes(userId.toString()) || data.includes(username);`
`if (bool) { }`

Comment: @Titus No, you don't want to `find` a `data` item.

Comment: @Bergi I know but this has the same effect, the `find` function will return an element if any of the elements in the array match the condition making the `if` statement `true` or `undefined` if no elements were found making the `if` statement false. It is also more efficient since the array will be iterated through only once.

Comment: @Titus It does *not* have the same effect when `userId` or `username` are falsy. When you don't want to `find` an array element, but get a boolean result from testing a predicate against `some` elements, just use the appropriate method. It's not even longer to type :-)

Comment: @Bergi But I guess this fails if the found element has a `falsy` value

Comment: @Bergi Yes, you're right, just realised that. I guess using `some` will me more appropriate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [the `some` Array method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) to test for multiple predicates. Either

```
if ([userId, userId.toString(), username].some(x => data.includes(x))) …
```

or

```
if (data.some(x => [userId, userId.toString(), username].includes(x))) …
```

Comment: Though its completely optional, some javascript style guides would say declaring the condition as a variable beforehand has easier readability as well as reusability.   
`let condition = [userId, userId.toString(), username].some(x => data.includes(x));`

Comment: @user3821538 That makes no sense, except you a) worry about line lengths b) have a good and descriptive variable name. `condition` isn't one.

Comment: lol, well `condition` is descriptive for this very stack overflow question. But it seems you proved it does make "some" sense all on your own.

Answer (score 1):

If you define `data` as object instead of array, the condition can be simplified to:

```
if (data[userId] || data[username]) console.log(true)
```

Also, the check will be `O(1)` instead of `O(n)`. Example:

```js
var data = {1:1, '2':1}

if (data[1]) console.log(1)
if (data[2]) console.log(2)
if (data['2']) console.log("'2'")
if (data[3] || data[2]) console.log('3 or 2')
```

or [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set):

```js
var data = new Set([1, '2'])

if (data.has(1)) console.log(1)
if (data.has(2)) console.log(2) // false
if (data.has('2')) console.log("'2'")
if (data.has(3) || data.has(2) || data.has('2')) console.log('3 or 2')
```

Answer (score 0):

Make flags using bitsets, such as this;

```
haveUserid = 1,
haveUsername = 2,
haveSchoolId = 4,
haveBadge = 8,
haveBlabla = 16,
```

Set the flag(let's say you want to set as haveUserid, haveUsername and haveBlabla)

```
data.flag = haveUserid + haveUsername + haveBlabla; // equals 1+2+8 = 11
```

and then you test the bits. I don't know if javascript has somekind of a function but you can also write a function of your own. That way you wouldn't have to write N amount of `data.includes` inside an if statement and just test the bits to see if `data.flag` satisfies your conditions.